# The difference between Lebesgue and Hardy spaces

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

Are there any known inequalities of the following type for $f$ satisfying some conditions:

$$
 \|f\|_{H_p(\mathbb{R})} \le C\|f\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R})},
$$

where $H_p$ denotes the real Hardy space and $p\le 1$ (otherwise the question would
be trivial)?

Here is an example:

If $f$ is bandlimited, then

$$
\|f\|_{H_p(\mathbb{R})} \sim \|f\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R})}.
$$

Does a similar conclusion also hold if $f$ is sufficiently smooth?

Of particular interest to me is the following case:

Assume that $\varphi$ satisfies the inequality above. Is the same true for any function in the
integer-shift-invariant space spanned by the integer shifts of $\varphi$?

Comment: Are you talking about real or complex Hardy spaces? For complex Hardy spaces the $H^p$ norm is just (a multiple of) the $L^p$ norm of the boundary function, so the inequality is in fact an equality. For real Hardy spaces, it's a totally different question, but I'm not familiar with them.


Comment: It might be worth adding that the $H^p$ notation can mean real Hardy spaces, complex Hardy spaces, or Sobolev spaces, and they're different things, so a bit more explanation might be good.

Comment: I have edited the original question to address your comments. Thanks. 

Comment: If we are talking about the same spaces, a characterization of the $H_1$ norm is
$$\|f\|_{H_1} = \|f \|_{L^1}+\sum\|R_j f\|_{L^1} $$
where $R_j$ are the Riesz operators with symbol $\xi_j/|\xi|$. So when $p=1$ the Hardy norm is strictly stronger.

Comment: I am talking about the real Hardy spaces which are defined e.g. by a Littlewood-Paley type decomposition. I am interested on results which rely on smoothness conditions on $f$. Of course, Hardy - and Lebesgue spaces are different for generic $f$. But if e.g. $f$ has bounded spectrum then the Hardy norm becomes comparable to the $L_p$ norm. I am asking to which extent this can be generalized by imposing smoothness conditions on $f$.

Comment: also, my interest is mainly $p<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Smoothness doesn't help much. Take any compactly supported smooth bump and put a few shifts of this bump far away to kill the first few moments. Then you get and $H^p$ function but the maximal operator will have a long stretch of $1/x$, which will give you a huge $H^p$ norm.

Your last question, as posed, also has negative answer: take this first example and add an $H^p$ function $f$ that satisfies the inequality and such that its norm is large but the norm of $f(x)-f(x+m)$ is small and $m$ is large (a stretch of a smooth atom renormalized properly would fit). Then the sum will satisfy the inequality because its norm sees only the good part but its difference with the shift by $m$ won't because its norm sees only the bad part.

What are you really after?

Comment: Hi Fedja,

first let me thank you for your nice answer(s). 

As far as I see it, your example could also be made to work with a bandlimited bump function. The larger the support of the spectrum, the larger the $H_p$ norm can get in comparison to the $L_p$ norm.

What if I impose that
\begin{equation}\label{1}
|\hat f(\xi)| \leq (1+|\xi|)^{-N}
\end{equation}
for some very large $N$.

This is somewhat similar to requiring that $\mbox{supp }\hat f \subset [-1,1]$ where the desired inequality holds by some classical results. Could such an inequality hold over all $f$ with (\ref{1})?

Comment: The bump example exploits the bad behavior of $\widehat f$ at $0$, not at $\infty$. You seem to forget that the Paley-Littlewood decomposition has infinitely many terms with extra-short supports of the FT, not just with extra-long ones. Your words "band limited" should really mean "with spectrum bounded away from both $0$ and $\infty$". 

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for my misunderstanding. So how about if we require that
$$
|\hat f(\xi)| \leq \min(1,|\xi\|^N)(1 + |\xi|)^{-N} ?
$$

My essential question is: Do we really need the compact support in the frequency domain or can we replace it with decay conditions?



Comment: The inequality is invariant under multiplication by constants and your decay conditions aren't, so there is a clear problem there.

Comment: Let us replace $\le$ by $\lesssim$. 

Comment: And what does this change? (or what exactly do you mean by $\lesssim$?)

Comment: i mean that the left hand side is bounded by a constant times the right hand side.

Comment: How can it possibly help if you *relax* the condition that is insufficient already?

Comment: The relaxed condition is invariant under multiplication by constants and it is the "right" analogue to the statement that a function has compact frequency support. So far all your objections apply to bandlimited functions as well, so I do not see why the decay condition is insufficient. Could you please expand on that? The essence of my question is "Do we need compact frequency support?". 